# make sure git histories are the same

Tags: git

I have a git repo of the Linux kernel. I made it with the standard git clone. Lets call that repo 'server'. I also have 'computer a' which did a clone of server. I developed on 'computer a' for a long time, then pushed back to 'server', but always in a separate branch. After some time I wanted to update server, so I ran the following on 'computer a'

```
git checkout master
git pull git://linus/kernel.git
git push origin master    #here origin is 'server'
```

So now my server's main branch could have changes in master that aren't from the main kernel repo. How can I find them, if any? In other words, how can I verify that the entire history in server/master is identical to Linus' master branch?

thanks

Comment: When you say "always in a separate branch", did you do your *development* on computer A in a separate branch, or did you develop on `master` and then *push* to a separate branch on server?

Comment: Simply compare the commit hashes of both master commits (`git rev-parse` is your friend)

Comment: I did my development on computer a, but never commited on master. I never did a commit on any master branch. At least I think. that's what I'm trying to verify. (maybe I did a cherry-pick or a merge at some point?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git makes it easy to *verify* that the entire history of two branches is the same:

- if the SHA1 commit IDs match, then the histories are identical
- else, the histories are different

The [git cherry](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry) command can help to identify commits that are not in the upstream branch, if the hashes are different.

Another tip is to use `git pull --ff-only` if you're pulling from an upstream branch and want to make sure that a merge with local work is *not* done. After using `--ff-only`, either the SHA1 commit IDs will match, or the whole command will fail.

Comment: so, if the latest SHA1 ID on server/master matches the latest linus/master, then, the ENTIRE history of both masters is the same? That must mean cherry-picking changes a commit's SHA1 id. I had never noticed.